# echo in init.rc

Tags: android, kernel, init

hi I want to add these scripts to init.rc but I get the error that init.rc doesnt support echo.

```
echo device > /sys/devices/platform/usbc.0/mode
```

what is the right way to do such a thing in init.rc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably use `write` for that. Something like:

```
write /sys/devices/platform/usbc.0/mode ${device}
```

Or if you literally want to write the string "device":

```
write /sys/devices/platform/usbc.0/mode "device"
```

Comment: device is not a variable, it's actually the word "device"

Comment: thank you.. I used the second line, working fine, real thanks :)